# Is the user logged in? (Angularfire2)

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am using Angular. Firebase is used to handle the Authentication. Angularfire2 library used.
My goal is to check if the user is logged in and if he is redirect him to another page. To check if the user logged in I am using authenticated() method. I am calling it three times in the constructor, ngOnInit and click event from the button. I am logged in, and I come back to the login page and I am getting:

```
false; // <-- authenticated() from constructor
false; // <-- authenticated() from ngOnInit
true; // <-- authenticated() after I pressed the button
```

I wrote a bunch of different methods with different approaches to check authentication but always got the same behaviour.

Is that a luck of understanding of some mechanisms in Angular? And if it is a way to redirect the user from login page if the user is logged in?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  private user: firebase.User;

  constructor(
    private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router,
    public snackBar: MdSnackBar,
  ) {
    this.user = angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser;
    this.authenticated();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authenticated();
  }

  login() {
    this.angularFireAuth.auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
      .then((u: firebase.User) => { this.router.navigate(['', u.uid]) })
      .catch((a: Error) => { this.openSnackBar(a) });
  }

  authenticated() {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var user = this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser
      if (user == null) {
        resolve(null);
      } else {
        reject(user);
      }
    }).then(
      (data) => { null; console.log(false); },
      (user) => { user; console.log(true); });
  }

  openSnackBar(a: Error) {
    this.snackBar.open(a.message, "Okay",
      {
        duration: 5000,
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: route guards can protect routes: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards if that is what you are looking for, not redirecting unless user is logged in.